# Aligning li in a straight line down

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

**Problem:**

I am having alignment issues on my website. I am using `display:inline;` to display some country flags on my website. The problem is with the `margin`, if the number beside the flag is more than single digits(Ex. 10 or more) it moves the text further because of the same `margin` being applied to it. That makes all the flags align differently depending on the number beside them.

**Question:** What would be the best way to align them in a straight line? (The maximum the number will be is 3 digits long.)

**P.S:** I don't even mind having 3 flags on one line but I would rather have them aligned straight all the way down.

**Here is the relevant code: (Full code in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yTm57/1/))**

**CSS:**

```
#visitor ul {
    font-size: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#visitor ul li {
    display:inline;
}
#visitor ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section id="visitor">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/28u467o.png" width="48" height="48" alt="US" />5</li>
        <li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/28u467o.png" width="48" height="48" alt="US" />55</li>
        <li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yTm57/1/)**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can fix the problem.

```
#visitor ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
```

The idea here is to give li a fixed width.

Comment: Such an easy solution! I guess, I wasn't thinking right! Thank you for your help!